# How to embed twitter timeline widget in HTML

Tags: html, twitter

I am trying to show twitter timeline of my website. I have created a widget from https://twitter.com/settings/widgets . twitter give me a code to embed my html file. This is the code

```
  <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/alamin0611" data-widget-id="598420614932779008">Tweets by @alamin0611</a> 
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s) [0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

But it is only showing `Tweets by @alamin0611` . I have search a lot but no luck. Please tell me the solution.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to achieve here. You want to show all tweets from twitter? not just one user?

Comment: want to show only my tweets

Comment: What is in the username field of configuration?

Comment: username is `alamin0611`

Comment: This is the result http://enterplus.be/feed2/

Comment: are you sure you've saved the widget? As its just showing the link which is part of the html.

Comment: Yes and twitter give me a code to embed @th0ward

Comment: Have you seen tweets? @th0ward

Comment: Yes. Please try above code. @th0ward

Comment: in the script tags have you changed this url https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js if I remove https:// it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the script tags have you changed this url platform.twitter.com/widgets.js if I remove https:// it works as expected.

Like so:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/alamin0611" data-widget-id="598420614932779008">Tweets by @alamin0611</a> 
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s) [0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Comment: Tried that, no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="300" data-height="400" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev">Tweets by TwitterDev</a> 

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

[my first answer in forum :)](https://jsfiddle.net/q1cL6tzp/)

Comment: Please do elaborate your answer with some information. Just the code snippet might not make sense to all the type of users who are facing this problem.

Comment: I copied the code from jsfiddle.com but all I get on my local page is a html link... The javascript console says: Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://platform.twitter.com/js/timeline.25e3f797ea5047ab5a8d06fd6ee7f701.js”.